# Query DynamboDB on partition key and sort key using aws-skd-java2

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a dyanmodb Table which i want to query using aws-skd-java2. Example codes only show using primary key

DynamoDbEnhancedClient client.....

//static schema to enhance cold starts

DynamoDbIndex index= client.table("DEV_ChildActivity", ChildActivity.TABLE_SCHEMA)
.index("roomId-index")

Now to Query:

```
QueryConditional keyValue = QueryConditional.keyEqualTo(Key.builder().partitionValue(roomid).build());
        QueryEnhancedRequest req = QueryEnhancedRequest.builder()
                .queryConditional(keyValue).build();

        SdkIterable<Page<ChildActivity>> result = index.query(req);
```

**Question**:
How do i include sort key of the index in request above? In the examples there is sample passing query request to DyanmodbClient but that return a low level list of Map, which i don't want to use. In version 1 of java api it was quite straightforward

Primary Partition Key:childId
Primary Sort Key:createdDateTime

GSI(roomId-Index)
Key:roomId(s)
Sort:createdDate(s)

Below are my dependencies

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>dynamodb</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion> 
                <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
                 <artifactId>apache-client</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>netty-nio-client</artifactId> </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
      <artifactId>dynamodb-enhanced</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>url-connection-client</artifactId> 
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 4):

In the [Key.Builder](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/enhanced/dynamodb/Key.Builder.html) class in the `software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb` package of the AWS SDK for java, there seems to be a `sortValue(sortValue)` function in addition to the `partitionValue(partitionValue)` that you used for the `Key` object for your `QueryConditional` object. Therefore, you should append a call to `sortValue` onto the result of `Key.builder().partitionValue(roomid)` before calling the `build()` function. So assuming the value of the sort key you want to query on is stored in a variable called `createdDate`, replace this line,

```
QueryConditional keyValue = QueryConditional.keyEqualTo(Key.builder().partitionValue(roomid).build());
```

with

```
QueryConditional keyValue = QueryConditional.keyEqualTo(Key.builder().partitionValue(roomid).sortValue(createdDate).build());
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my full java example to find an item using `DynamoDbEnhancedClient`:

```
 public void findByPartitionAndSortKey(String partitionKey, String sortKey) {
        
     DynamoDbTable<MyObject> myObjTable = dynamoDbEnhancedClient.table("my_table", TableSchema.fromBean(MyObject.class));

      QueryConditional queryConditional = 
      QueryConditional.keyEqualTo(Key.builder()
                      .partitionValue(partitionKey)
                      .sortValue(sortKey) //not required if you dont have a sort key
                      .build());

            PageIterable<MyObject> results = myObjTable.query(queryConditional);

     results.stream().forEach(p-> p.items().forEach(item -> System.out.println(item) //process));
          

    }
```